# How do i make a bot that responds to one specific user? Discord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py

I want a bot that responds to one user, not by looking for a keyword, just any text they send into any channel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply just check if the user's id is same from your code. Below is an `on_message` that checks if the author of the message has the user id of `xxx` make sure to set it yourself. This would always trigger the event whenever a message has been sent, but only send the message if the user id matches

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):

    if message.author.id == 000000000000:
        await message.channel.send('Hello')
```

Next time it's best if you show an example of what you have tried, so we can fix or show examples of your code.

Comment: Thank you, and I'll keep in mind to send the code I tried to use